# How to browse bash history between certain line numbers

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, history

Every time I need this I Google it like 10 minutes. I don't know how to express this better, but I need to retrieve bash history between certain lines like:

```
$ history --start 321 --end 456
#to retrieve history from 321 and to 456
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use something like

```bash
history | grep -A 135 -w 321
```

It starts with line 321 and shows the next 135 lines, so it will show lines 321 to 456.

Answer (score 10):

Use [head](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/head) and [tail](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/tail):

```bash
history | head -n 456 | tail -n 136
```

Which will get the first 456 (up to the end you want) and then you get the last 136 (which computes as 456 - 136 = 320, but will fetch from the 321st record from history).

Comment: This isn't quite right since the command numbers don't equal line numbers. I'm assuming OP is asking command numbers. If you hit enter with empty command line, or run the same command multiple times, these aren't put into the history file but the command numbers are increased.

Comment: @Aerith please explain with an example, history has different options, you can discard duplicates or not, empty.lines usually are not in the history as being ignored...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean command numbers and not line numbers. I would use `sed` to give me the lines in the file between the two command numbers.

```
$ history | sed -n '/^ 321 /,/^ 456 /p'
```

`^` character matches at the start of the line. Also a space after the number to make sure `^ 321` doesn't match line equalling `32155 ls`

Comment: I was meaning line numbers but thank you for your contribution, it's worth to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below strives for the **least** dependencies, **least** mathematical calculation, **maximal** readability(tested under GNU `grep`):

```sh
# Display history lines exactly from line321 to line456
history | grep -A $((456-321)) '321\ \ '

# Or throw away 'Space Escaping', a even 
# more simple command we'd get , but the output 
# will contain one more line, which is this command itself.
history | grep -A $((456-321)) '321  '
```

with output:

```
321 some-command
322 some-command
...
...
...
456 some-command
```

Comment: What's so special about GNU grep? Even [busybox](http://www.busybox.net) grep has the `-A` command line option.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Thanks for pointing it out. I have refined the wording.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way is to use sed's print (p) command with an address range

```
history | sed -n '321,456p'
```

from the sed(1p) man page:

> The -n flag supresses the default output (in which each line, after it is examined  for  editing, is written to standard output). Only lines explicitly selected for output are written.